# Pandas - filter users with minimum artists listened to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, group-by

I want to filter my dataset to users who have listened to a minimum number of unique artists. My aim is to focus on users with relatively higher listenership as a function of artist selection.

Below is a data example and my initial code approach:

```
full_df.head()

   user artist              plays  gender  age    Country
0   a   devendra banhart    456    m       28.0   United States
1   b   boards of canada    407    m       28.0   United States
2   a   cocorosie           386    m       28.0   United States
3   c   aphex twin          213    m       28.0   United States
4   d   animal collective   203    m       28.0   United States
```

Code:

```
eda_df = full_df.groupby('users')['artist'].filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 20)
```

In this case, user a would display the highest artist count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`pd.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html).

This example, using your data, filters for a minimum unique artist count by user of 1:

```
res = df[df.groupby('user')['artist'].transform('nunique') > 1]

print(res)

  user           artist  plays gender   age       Country
0    a  devendrabanhart    456      m  28.0  UnitedStates
2    a        cocorosie    386      m  28.0  UnitedStates
```